# How to get mysql select join result as 1 dimension array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this select join query to get associated doctor ids only knowing the id for table b. The results look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 40 ) )
```

What I want is like this, the same but without the extra array [id]:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 40  )
```

Here is the query:

```
  select a.doctor_id as id from assigned_doctors a INNER JOIN appointments b
  ON a.appointment_number = b.appointment_number WHERE b.id = 283
```

Is there some way I can change the query to get that result? I guess this format is caused by using the join. Not a big deal, but would rather not have to deal with the indexes.

Comment: What method are you using to return the data?

Comment: Yes, show your PHP `fetch()` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your fetch to only store the `id` and not the entire row array.  You haven't shown it, but regardless of the API it is similar:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

If you've gotten this through a `fetchAll()` or just for future reference, you can just extract the `id` column from the array of row arrays:

```
$ids = array_column($rows, 'id');
```

Comment: I am pretty much only doing $result = mysqli_query(query) and the result looks this way

Comment: No, you must fetch rows from the result.

Comment: Duh, you're right. We are using a wrapper for database functions, there's a fetch function I was able to change to get what I need

Answer (score 2):

```
    We can use like this to get result :

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $ids[$row['id']] = $row['id'];
    }

    array_keys($ids);
OR array_values($ids);
```